# offset and length are out of bound for array or count is greater than

Tags: c#, arrays

Getting error for some inputs : offset and length are out of bound for array or count is greater than

```
public int RemoveDuplicates(int[] nums)
        {
            int curr = 1;
            int prev = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                if(nums[i] > nums[curr] && nums[i] != nums[prev])
                {
                    nums[curr] = nums[i];
                    curr++;
                    prev++;
                }
            }

            return curr;
        }
```

Comment: What inputs cause this error? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think you need to account for isLast = i == (nums.Length - 1). Because otherwise "nums[curr]" could be out of bounds on the last iteration

Comment: I suspected curr as well, but I cannot see how curr can get larger than i, and the limits for i are checked in the for loop. The error message would also be a different one. I guess the problem lies in the creation of nums[]

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach:

```
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 1 };
nums = nums.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that OP's method returns an `int`, whereas yours returns an `int` array. They do different things.